# Swipe To Delete songs in a playlist

Tags: ios, iphone, ipod.app

Is it possible to delete a song from a playlist with a 'swipe to delete'? I thought this was possible, but I am not able to do this. I'm running iOS 5.0.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right. You **can't** delete songs in a playlist with a swipe. Only the way Nathan described. Hit the "Edit" button on top of the window, and remove the songs with the familiar red *road sign*.

[image]

You should be able to do this with a swipe on a whole Playlists, Artists, Songs, Albums, …

[image]

And make note you can't delete songs with a swipe from iCloud.

Answer (score 1):

Swipe to delete only appears to happen in the 'Songs' tab of the Music app. To remove songs from a playlist I only get the option of hitting Edit at the top of the playlist, then using the red icon on the left of the song name. - iOS 5.1